# Retrieve value from model into view ib MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    /* public string Browse()
     {
         return "Hello from Browse";

     public string Details(int id)
     {
         string message = "Store.Details, ID = " + id;

         return message;
        // return "Hello from Details";
     }*/

  public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
      var album = new Album { Title = "Album " + id };
       return View(album);
    }
}
```

I am new to MVC 3 ,My View is Details.aspx without Razor  engine.

```
 <html>
 <head runat="server">
    <title>Details</title>
  </head>
       <body>
          <div>

          </div>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Can you suggest me a tutorial for MVC3 without razor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not using the Razor view engine (ala MVC 2) you should be able to do it like this...

At top of page...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.Models.Album>" %>
```

**NOTE**: `MyNamespace.Models.Album` needs to match you Model class

then...

```
<div>
    <%: Model.Title %>
</div>
```

...to be honest, I am assuming what would have worked in MVC2 will be the same in webforms view engine in MVC 3. I have always used Razor for MVC 3... not sure why you would avoid :S

Comment: Didn't you mean `<%: Model.Title %>`?

Comment: Can you suggest me a tutorial for MVC3 without razor

Answer (score 0):

In your view, do this:

```
@model Your.Namespace.Album <!--tell the view to use the model - at the very top of the page-->
....

<div>
<!--To print the Title-->
@Model.Title

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like:

```
<!-- Partial code -->
<body>
     <div>

          <%: Model.Title %>

     </div>
</body>
```